# getting force close application if GPS disabled

Tags: android, gps, location

I have application to get location from gps
but if GPS disabled my application getting force close
in emulator it's fine not error,but if run in device it's force close
how can i do this??
this is my code:

```
public class Track extends Activity implements LocationListener{
String curTime;
double lat;
double lng;
double alt;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    final String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Dbhelper helper = new Dbhelper(this);
    final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    updateWithNewLocation(null);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            db.isOpen();
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO location (longitude,latitude,altitude,tgl_buat) VALUES " +
                    "('"+lng+"','"+lat+"','"+alt+"','"+curTime+"')");
            //db.close();
        }
    }, 10*60*1000, 10*60*1000);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, (10*60*1000), 10,
                                           locationListener);
    PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,
      "PackageName = " + info.packageName + "\nVersionCode = "
        + info.versionCode + "\nVersionName = "
        + info.versionName + "\nPermissions = "+info.permissions, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("PackageName = " + info.packageName + "\nVersionCode = "
        + info.versionCode + "\nVersionName = "
        + info.versionName + "\nPermissions = "+info.permissions);
}
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
      updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                                Bundle extras){ }
  };
  public void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {


        if (location != null) {
            Dbhelper helper = new Dbhelper(this);
            final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
            curTime = df.format(time);
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            alt = location.getAltitude();
            System.out.println(lat);
            System.out.println(lng);
            System.out.println(alt);
            /*db.execSQL("INSERT INTO location (longitude,latitude,altitude,tgl_buat) VALUES " +
            "('"+lng+"','"+lat+"','"+alt+"','"+curTime+"')");
            db.close();*/
            /*Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO location (longitude,latitude,altitude,tgl_buat) VALUES " +
                            "('"+lng+"','"+lat+"','"+alt+"','"+curTime+"')");
                    db.close();
                }
            }, 10*60*1000, 10*60*1000);*/

          } 
       }
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

please give me a solution..thank you for feed back :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to turn on GPS enabled automatically in your app, I'm afraid there is no way other than prompt the user.

You can achieve that easily with modifying onProviderDisabled() method in your LocationListener. The idea is to open a dialog asking user to turn on GPS:

```
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) 
    {
        showDialog(CHOICE_GPS_ENABLE);          
    }
```

add in your activity:

```
    protected final static int CHOICE_GPS_ENABLE = 1; //or any other number

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch (id)
    {
        case CHOICE_GPS_ENABLE:
            dialog = createGPSEnableDialog();
            break;

        default:
            dialog = super.onCreateDialog(id);
            break;
    }

    return dialog;
}

    protected Dialog createGPSEnableDialog()
{
    Dialog toReturnGPS;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("You don't have GPS enabled. Go to Settings and enable GPS?");

    builder.setTitle("GPS failed");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, enable GPS",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                        {
                          Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                          startActivity(intent);
                        }
                });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No, quit application",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                        {
                            onDestroy();
                        }
                });

    toReturnGPS = builder.create();
    return toReturnGPS;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> i want GPS turn on automatically if my application running
>   how can i do this??

I don't think you can do anything beyond prompt the user to turn it on. So Im afraid you are going to be unable to make your application work how you'd like.

Comment: my application not to publish..it's use for my company internal business..sorry if you're afraid :)

Comment: @deadbabaz  You can't automatically turn on GPS. However there are hacks which you can do if the device is rooted.

Comment: OK, thank you for your suggestion..but how can i fix my problem?my application get force close if gps disabled..please give me a suggestion..thank you :) @ngen

Comment: Check the logcat, find out what exception is being thrown. Wrap your code in a try catch that will handle the exception gracefully. Or find a getter on the location manager or something that will let you know that the gps reciever is off, and wrap your code in an if statement that calls that getter.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Location locationtest;
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          locationtest=location;
          updateWithNewLocation(locationtest);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
              locationtest= null;
              updateWithNewLocation(locationtest);
            }
```

instead of

```
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
      updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }
```

Comment: it's doesn't work too..i still get force close when running application if gps disabled..i try with more way but it's still not working..can you give another suggest?thank you :)